# Matching 17.3nch with spaCy Entity Ruler

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to match screen sizes with the entity ruler from spaCy.

For example: ['14"',  '7.1-ch', '15.2nch']

The first and second are easy, because they will be tokenized like this: '14' '"' '7.1' '-' 'ch'

The problem is to match the '15.2nch' as it is a whole token. I tried:

{"label": "inches", "pattern": [
{"SHAPE": {"IN": ["dd.d", "dd", "d.d", "d"]}, "ORTH": 'nch'}]}

But when I apply two patterns in the same token it does not work.

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Thanks